# Did medieval squires and pages have their own servants?

Tags: nobility

The squires and pages in the middle ages acted almost as personal servants of the knights. Apart from their trainings, they looked after the personal needs of their masters, such as cleaning clothes and armoury, delivering messages, waiting on the table etc.

But as the pages and squires used to come from nobility themselves, did they also have personal servants to look after their similar needs? Or the pages/ squires had to do these things on their own?

Comment: "the pages and squires used to come from nobility themselves"...did they? I find that very hard to believe. The servants for the monarchy might have been nobles in some cases (there was potential for advancement for that) but being a servant for a lowly knight seems very unlikely.

Comment: I haven't looked into the history myself, but most period fiction I read pages and squires are young male progeny of the nobility, training under an established knight.

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: @KillingTime  Actual medieval kings and nobles had noble servants.  There are records of a household where the highest ranking servant had three servants of his own, and the highest ranking of those three had a servant of his own.  By the time you get to knights, sure it's less likely.

Comment: I think that depended a lot on the social status of the squires.